# Logstash Create an array of values from string

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am having a following set of information in my logs. It is in JSON format.

```
{   
  "someField":"someValue",   
  "columns":"[colName1, colName2, colName3, ... colNameN]", 
  "someField":"someValue" 
}
```

I want this to be stored as an array in a same field `columns`.

The usecase I want to show up is how many users have used the particular column called `colName1` and the count of it.

I am using `ELK stak 5.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution by referring both the above answers.
This is what I did.

To remove `[` and `]` from the string I used this:

```
mutate {
        gsub => ["columns", "[\[\]]", ""]
    }
```

and then to convert it into array:

```
    mutate {
        split => { "columns" => "," }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if your source is directly json format

use the json plugin

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

The array field will auto convert to array

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

Comment: I understand that it it will be auto convert to array. but in my case I am using ThreadContext to put the value. and ThreadContext only supports `String` vales. so although my values looks in an array format, they are actually exported in string format in a log file. So will that affact in this case?

Comment: ThreadContext  is the logstash plugin ? if not the json format that you provide should come from message field by default, so i don't know you means ThreadContext

Comment: No its not logstash plugin but it is a library in java that helps me to put values in a field and use it across.

Comment: @VishalKinjavdekar i think your data will still come through the message ,could you check ?

Comment: I checked... In kibana it shows as a text field even after using json plugin

Comment: "[colName1, colName2, colName3, ... colNameN]" in json format can't be the array ,it will think as string because your outer " "

Comment: so maybe need ruby to change to array

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I found the solution by combining both the answers. :)

Comment: i see you use as string then use mutate to split as array

Answer (score 1):

Mutate in output.conf might help you.

Follow this link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-replace

Although direct conversion from string to array is not supported. I faced same use case some time back, used merge functionality for that. I would suggest have some dummy field and merge with 'columns' field to create new array field. Hope this helps.